# File under data/data/<package_name>/files not showing in my Android Device

Tags: android, file, android-emulator, inputstream, fileoutputstream

I am making an app that will fetch the server logs and store it in end-users android phone. I am reading and writing the file using InputStream and FileOutputStream which generates a new text file under data/data/<package_name>/files folder of Emulator. However, it is not showing in my physical android device when connected through USB. Used below logic:

```
   try{
        Session session = new JSch().getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                logs.append(line);
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(logs.getBytes());
                Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Is there any way, I could view this file in my phone without rooting and giving some permissions or any better alternative? Highly appreciate your inputs guys.

[Device File Explorer Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Z0Y.png)

Comment: You stored the files in app private storage. Hence they are ...  private to your app only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give permissions to access Storage in AndroidManifest.xml and add below logic for writing data to your device storage at data/data/<package_name>/files :

```
    String dirPath = FILE_PATH;
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(FILE_PATH), filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Written to your Storage!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```